# Is event bubbling supported by all browsers?

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

jQuery uses event bubbling strategy to handle events.

And it claims to be cross browser,

but is "event bubbling" supported by all browsers?

There is another strategy: event capturing, which is reverse to event bubbling,is it extinct?

Or my question could be re-stated as:

**Can Javascript decides on whether choosing "event capturing" strategy or "event bubbling" strategy by itself?**

Comment: Why the -1 ? seems to be a legitimate question.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 5):

All browsers? No. Lynx, for instance, doesn't support JavaScript at all.

However, event bubbling is a standard DOM feature. The jQuery documentation is not lying to you.

Comment: Don't forget there is also event capturing strategy,where is it used or is it extinct?

Comment: capturing lends itself to unexpected outcomes as well, but you can read more about that here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.  It gets tricky - as capturing to me is like a 'box of chocolates' [ie, black-box] - as you may or may not know what's in the deep end; whereas if i'm inside the 'black-box' triggering something, i typically know how i got there or how to get out (ie, 'bubbling'). :) Anyways, that quirks page offers a concise (as always) explanation.

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery [compatibility page](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility), it supports the following browsers:

- Firefox 2+
- IE6+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9+
- Chrome 1+

All of which support event bubbling.

According to the [W3Schools browser usage page](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) those browsers account for **99.2%** of all browser usage in July 2009, I'd say this is cross-browser support covered. Ignore those [peddling pointless pedantry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283980/is-event-bubbling-supported-by-all-browsers/1283990#1283990) about browser support being all or nothing. If you're a user of any other browser you are probably far enough from the mainstream to have your own methods of dealing with browser issues.

Comment: My main concern now focuses on how javascript chooses to hook on "event capturing" or "event bubbling" phase of model?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. Netscape Navigator 4 doesn't support it, but I don't think there's a lot of worry about supporting Netscape 4 these days.

Answer (score -4):

Either they are lying, or the definition for "Cross-Browser" needs to be slightly altered. It's either cross-browser or it isn't there's no in-between.

Comment: The "Cross Browser" heading on the jQuery homepage clearly shows what it means if you hover it, and there are further details under "Supported Browsers" in the docs. To summarize, every significant browser for desktop platforms released in the past several years is supported, with many older or less common browsers working just fine (but without being specifically supported targets).

Comment: "every significant browser"... Then it's not completely cross-browser is it? ... No, it isn't.

Comment: It runs on more than one browser. Therefore it is cross-browser. The only thing that needs altering is your misunderstanding of the phrase.

Comment: um no...

Web definitions for Cross-browser
 Cross-browser refers to the ability for a website, web application, HTML construct or client-side script to support all the web browsers. ...
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser - Definition in context